# How to store and print the command value in a variable

Tags: shell-script

I am running below sed command and storing it in a variable, however when echoing the variable it doesn't show any output.

```
new_ip=$(sed -i 's/\./-/g' iplist)
echo $new_ip
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you need to store a file content in a variable?!

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `-i` (in place) option for sed which will modify the file in place and produce no output.  Your `iplist` file has presumably been modified to replace all periods with dashes but there is no output to store in the `new_ip` variable.  You can remove the `-i` option if your intent isn't to modify the file in place.

Also you should quote variable expansions

```
echo "$new_ip"
```

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: @Chinkleet you should accept the answer if it solve your issues